# ruby on rails console processes in the background

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

Is there a way to run processes from rails script/console in the background?
I have a onetime lib script that will take two or so days to execute and I want to set this to run in the background.

Something like:

```
script/console
```

Then:

```
>> load 'script.rb' &
```

In the commandline I'd just do:

```
$ command &
```

I did find: http://backgroundrb.rubyforge.org/ but this seemed like overkill for just this onetime task.

I also tried:

```
$ ruby data_importer2.rb &
```

This doesn't import the active record stuff though (error: uninitialized constant ActiveRecord)

Thanks!

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You can do this with the script runner instead of the console:

```
./script/runner script.rb &
```

Answer (score 2):

You could use script/runner, or if you need to run it again at some point, the easiest way would be to wrap it in a rake task.

Answer (score 2):

```
$ script/console
>> fork { load 'script.rb' }
>> Process.detach
>> # ...
```